# Method Definition In MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need to implement a method in an MVC Controller. The controller is

```
public class OurBoxesController : Controller
```

and the method

```
public static DateTime Next(this DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        int start = (int)from.DayOfWeek;
        int target = (int)dayOfWeek;
        if (target <= start)
            target += 7;
        return from.AddDays(target - start);
    }
```

I have this erro"Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class". I have understand, but i don't understand where i must to put the method to use it in the controller. Thank you

Comment: Why does your method need to be static?  I think that's your problem.

Comment: If i remove static the problem is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says, you have to put it in a **non-generic static class**.  Something like this:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime Next(this DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        int start = (int)from.DayOfWeek;
        int target = (int)dayOfWeek;
        if (target <= start)
            target += 7;
        return from.AddDays(target - start);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the method to be in your controller, it can't be an extension method:

```
public static DateTime Next(DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    int start = (int)from.DayOfWeek;
    int target = (int)dayOfWeek;
    if (target <= start)
        target += 7;
    return from.AddDays(target - start);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are trying to add is considered an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var nextMonday = dateTime.Next(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Extension methods must be placed in a `public static class ExtensionsMethods` (the name of the class does not matter).

You can either add this method as non-extension method (that is to remove the `this` keyword) or add it to a static class outside of your `OurBoxesController` class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this inside an Static Class.

Like this:

```
static class ExtensionHelper
{

public static DateTime Next(this DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        int start = (int)from.DayOfWeek;
        int target = (int)dayOfWeek;
        if (target <= start)
            target += 7;
        return from.AddDays(target - start);
    }
}
```

hope this help

Comment: I am in a controller of mvc...not in a static class

Comment: you have to create this static class :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `this` in your method definition. By putting `this` before your *from* parameter, you are making the method as an Extension method and that must be defined in **static non generic class**

```
public static DateTime Next(DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
```

[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)